# multi item replacing in cuda thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have a device vector A,B,C as following.

```
A = [1,1,3,3,3,4,4,5,5]
B = [1,3,5]
C = [2,8,6]
```

So I want to replace each of B in a with corresponding element in C.
Eg:

- 1 is replaced by 2,
- 3 is replaced by 8,
- 5 is replaced by 6

so as to get the following result

```
Result = [2,2,8,8,8,4,4,6,6]
```

How do I achieve this in cuda thrust or any way of implementing it in cuda C++. I found thrust::replace which replaces single element at once. Since I need to replace huge amount of data, it becomes bottleneck to replace one at a time.

Comment: what are typical sizes for `A` and `B`? Does `B` just contain 3 values?

Comment: @m.s. A can contain values in range if million. sizeof B and C is <= size of A

Answer (score 2):

This can be done efficiently by first building a map and then applying a custom functor which queries the map.

The example code does the following steps:

1. Get the largest element of `C`. This assumes that your data is already sorted.
2. Create a map vector of size `largest_element`. Copy the new values at the position of the old ones.
3. Apply the `mapper` functor to `A`. This functor reads `new_value` from the map vector. If this `new_value` is **not** `0`, the value in `A` is replaced by the new value. This assumes that `C` will never contain `0`. If it can contain `0`, you must use another condition, e.g. initialize the map vector with `-1` and check if `new_value != -1`

---

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/scatter.h>
#include <iostream>


#define PRINTER(name) print(#name, (name))
template <template <typename...> class V, typename T, typename ...Args>
void print(const char* name, const V<T,Args...> & v)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\t";
    thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


template <typename T>
struct mapper
{
    mapper(thrust::device_ptr<const T> map) : map(map)
    {
    }

    __host__ __device__
    void operator()(T& value) const
    {
       const T& new_value = map[value]; 
       if (new_value)
       {
          value = new_value;
       }
    }

    thrust::device_ptr<const T> map;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace thrust::placeholders;

    int A[] = {1,1,3,3,3,4,4,5,5};
    int B[] = {1,3,5};
    int C[] = {2,8,6};

    int size_data    = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    int size_replace = sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0]);

    // copy demo data to GPU
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_A (A, A+size_data);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_B (B, B+size_replace);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_C (C, C+size_replace);

    PRINTER(d_A);
    PRINTER(d_B);
    PRINTER(d_C);

    int largest_element = d_C.back();

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_map(largest_element);

    thrust::scatter(d_C.begin(), d_C.end(), d_B.begin(), d_map.begin());
    PRINTER(d_map);

    thrust::for_each(d_A.begin(), d_A.end(), mapper<int>(d_map.data()));
    PRINTER(d_A);

    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
d_A:    1   1   3   3   3   4   4   5   5   
d_B:    1   3   5   
d_C:    2   8   6   
d_map:  0   2   0   8   0   6   
d_A:    2   2   8   8   8   4   4   6   6
```