# Retain Duplicates with Set Intersection in CUDA

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm using CUDA and THRUST to perform paired set operations. I would like to **retain duplicates**, however. For example:

```
int keys[6] = {1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5};
int vals[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int comp[2] = {1, 5};

thrust::set_intersection_by_key(keys, keys + 6, comp, comp + 2, vals, rk, rv);
```

Desired result

```
rk[1, 1, 1, 5, 5]
rv[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

Actual Result

```
rk[1, 5]
rv[5, 7]
```

I want all of the **vals** where the corresponding **key** is contained in **comp**.

Is there any way to achieve this using thrust, or do I have to write my own kernel or thrust function?

I'm using this function: [set_intersection_by_key](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__set__operations.html#ga77564b343a17454dfb672a2acad7f80f).

Comment: Yes: sorry about that. I'll update the post - [documentation](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__set__operations.html#ga77564b343a17454dfb672a2acad7f80f)

Comment: The set intersection retains duplicates, but only the number of duplicates which are in both sets. In your example, there are no duplicates. It sounds like you don't really want the set intersection at all, although I'm not sure what you would call the operation you describe

Comment: Instead of *intersection*, this appears to be sone kind of filtering operation where you create the result vectors based on a predicate (the predicate being the question if the key is contained in `comp`)

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is analogous to a SQL Inner Join: a filter that excludes any values where the key is not contained in the second set. Intersection is the closest thing I could come up with. Perhaps filter functions would be more appropriate, but I don't see anything like that in the version of thrust I have with CUDA 7.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [thrust documentation](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__set__operations.html#ga77564b343a17454dfb672a2acad7f80f):

> The generalization is that if an element appears m times in [keys_first1, keys_last1) and n times in [keys_first2, keys_last2) (where m may be zero), then it appears min(m,n) times in the keys output range

Since `comp` does only contain each key once, `n=1` and therefore `min(m,1) = 1`.

In order to get "all of the **vals** where the corresponding **key** is contained in **comp**", you can use the approach of [my answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31294395/678093).

Similarly, the example code does the following steps:

1. Get the largest element of `d_comp`. This assumes that `d_comp` is already sorted.
2. Create vector `d_map` of size `largest_element+1`. Copy `1` to all  positions of the entries of `d_comp` in `d_map`.
3. Copy all entries from `d_vals` for which there is a `1` entry in `d_map` into `d_result`.

   ```
   #include <thrust/device_vector.h>
   #include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
   #include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
   #include <thrust/functional.h>
   #include <thrust/copy.h>
   #include <thrust/scatter.h>
   #include <iostream>


   #define PRINTER(name) print(#name, (name))
   void print(const char* name, const thrust::device_vector<int>& v)
   {
       std::cout << name << ":\t";
       thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));
       std::cout << std::endl;
   }

   int main()
   {
       int keys[] = {1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5};
       int vals[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
       int comp[] = {1, 5};

       const int size_data = sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]);
       const int size_comp = sizeof(comp)/sizeof(comp[0]);

       // copy data to GPU
       thrust::device_vector<int> d_keys (keys, keys+size_data);
       thrust::device_vector<int> d_vals (vals, vals+size_data);
       thrust::device_vector<int> d_comp (comp, comp+size_comp);

       PRINTER(d_keys);
       PRINTER(d_vals);
       PRINTER(d_comp);

       int largest_element = d_comp.back();

       thrust::device_vector<int> d_map(largest_element+1);

       thrust::constant_iterator<int> one(1);
       thrust::scatter(one, one+size_comp, d_comp.begin(), d_map.begin());
       PRINTER(d_map);

       thrust::device_vector<int> d_result(size_data);
       using namespace thrust::placeholders;
       int final_size = thrust::copy_if(d_vals.begin(),
                                       d_vals.end(),
                                       thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_map.begin(), d_keys.begin()),
                                       d_result.begin(),
                                       _1
                                       ) - d_result.begin();
       d_result.resize(final_size);

       PRINTER(d_result);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

**output**:

```
d_keys:     1   1   1   3   4   5   5   
d_vals:     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
d_comp:     1   5   
d_map:      0   1   0   0   0   1   
d_result:   1   2   3   6   7
```

Comment: This is fantastic and has really helped me understand how to use some of the features in thrust, but I think there may be a caveat here with regards to memory size. I expect the keys to be in the millions. My max value is currently 2757476, which would require ~10 MB of memory for the map. Could the map be a char type instead?

Comment: @Robear you could use `char`, but also `bool`, it does not really matter (maybe in terms of performance, but you would need to benchmark that). But is 10 MB really a problem?

Comment: Nah 10MB is no problem, but I try to be conscious of scaling issues, and memory's at a premium on these cards; I can see this scaling up by a factor of 10. With char, though, the map is going to be 1/4 the size of comp. If comp ever gets that large, my working-memory is probably not going to be my biggest problem.

The solution is fantastic, though, and exactly what I needed. I can work out the details later and I'll post up my code and benchmarks. I'm also going to try a kernel which performs a check on every possible combination of the two sets. No memory overhead, but at a performance cost

Comment: I'll mark as answer as soon as I vet the code in my application. Thanks!

Comment: @Robear If you want to experiment with thrust, you could also call [`thrust::binary_search`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__binary__search.html#gaca71baf79a6985712d8e5bdc1dcdbaa9) from a custom functor; this will also avoid any memory overhead at the cost of computational overhead

Comment: I was able to improve performance by using a stencil generated by binary_search in lieu of the permutation_iterator and scatter. This reduced execution time to ~200ms instead of ~300ms for 10M elements. Still, this is slower than the CPU, and about 100x slower than the other vectorized operations I have implemented :(

Comment: @Robear you could post a new question containing a [mcve]

Comment: Should I post a new question or perhaps just edit this one to be more complete?

Comment: @Robear If you have specific questions regarding performance, you should ask a new question containing complete examples of all of your implementations with datasets, time measurement code etc. It should be reproducible by copy & paste.

Comment: I checked the source code and it looks like thrust is doing a simple nested loop operation. Looks like commenting out **line 118** in `thrust\system\detail\sequential\set_operations.h` _(version 1.8)_ will solve my problem, but I need to test it. If it works, I'll just copy / paste the thrust call chain to make another method with the updated functionality so I don't break anything existing. That should yield similar performance to what I had originally, which was < 10ms @ 100M elements. Should I just post that code here, since it's not really another question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87535/discussion-between-robear-and-m-s).