# Thrust adapting thrust::remove_if so predicate is checking for existence in range

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have two vectors which have been zipped together. And a third vector which stores a subset of the unique values found on the first vector in the zipped vectors. I am trying to filter the zipped vectors such that only rows whose first vector values appear in the filter vector are left in the two zipped vectors.

So lets values in the vectors that I have zipped together are (sorted according to the left value):

```
1|0
1|1
2|1
3|1
3|2
```

And values in the filter vector are (corresponding to the first column an d sorted):

```
1
3
```

I want my output to become:

```
1|0
1|1
3|1
3|2
```

Such that 2|1 was filtered out because the value 2 was not found in the filter vector.

Right now I am planning on making an implementation which uses the Vectorized Searches module. So use thrust::binary_search to search for the values on the left side of the tuple in the filter vector. The output on whether or not each element was found in the range being searched then becomes a stencil which I use to run thrust::remove_if over the zipped vectors.

It feels very inefficient given the fact that the two zipped vectors are already sorted in the order of the left hand value. Is there a better way to tackle this problem with thrust?

Comment: what are the sizes of these vectors in practice?  especially what is the typical size or size range for the filter vector?

Comment: Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085545/retain-duplicates-with-set-intersection-in-cuda).  If the filter vector length is trivially short, I would just write a custom functor to pass to remove_if to do the comparison, iterating through the values in the filter vector.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case. In my current case the limit of it is 40k records but it could be much longer. (e.g. up to about 1M)

Comment: awesome I will test out the other solution you suggested in your second comment.